# @media screen css property only read two rules

Tags: css, responsive-design, media

```
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) 
{/***style****/}

@media only screen and (min-width:400px) and (max-width:700px) 
{/***style****/}

@media only screen and (max-width:700px) 
{/***style****/}
```

The media in the middle doesn't respond. Why?

Comment: what is your device screen width ?

Comment: This also depends on the device's browser's implementation of the standard. What's the device and browser (a.k.a. user agent)?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of two reasons:

1. Your *second and third* media queries are both essentially the same;
2. Given the nature of **cascading** stylesheets, the styles contained within the *third* media query will rule over those within the *second* media query.

Try removing the third media query, and see if you have any joy then.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:400px) 
{/***style****/}

@media only screen and (min-width:401px) and (max-width:700px) 
{/***style****/}
```